# Regular Expression for R.layout in java files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Requirement

> Regex for R.layout.*anyfile* in file and want the string *anyfile* in a variable

Example

in java file `setContentView(R.layout.fragment) ;`
python variable should return `fileName = fragment`

IN PYTHON

Comment: Why are you parsing raw `R.layout` files?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please see updated question

Comment: @AbhinavJordiieDas Any restrictions on what `anyfile` can be, meaning what kind of characters it is allowed to contain

Comment: @FlyingTeller no just small characters (xml naming convention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
re.findall("R\.layout\.([a-z]*)", "setContentView(R.layout.fragment) ;")
```

Which outputs a list of the matches in the second argument, here that would be:

```
['fragment']
```

Note: If there are any additional characters allowed in `anyfile`, just add them between `[]`. For example to add hyphens: `[a-z-]`